Iterate over points in Cartesian product of arrays, ordered by taxicab distance from a point
I have an array of integer arrays - for example:
[
    [11, 9, 13, 7, 15, 6, 16, 4, 18, 2, 20, 0, 22],
    [4, 3, 10, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0, 8],
    [9, 7, 11, 6, 12, 5, 13,  4, 14, 2, 16, 17, 0]
]

I'd like to iterate over all points in the Cartesian product of the arrays, sorted by their taxicab distance from the point consisting of the first elements from each array. So, in the case of the example, I would like to iterate over all distinct 3-tuples whose first, second, and third elements respectively belong to the first, second, and third array in the input, starting with the tuple (11, 4, 9), and proceeding in ascending order of their taxicab distance from (11, 4, 9).
So, for the example input above...

there would be 1521 elements in the result (since the three arrays respectively have length 13, 9, and 13, and 13×9×13=1521)
the first element of the result would be (11, 4, 9)
the second element would be (11, 3, 9) - the only point in the Cartesian product of the inputs with a distance of exactly 1 from (11, 4, 9)
the next six elements would be (9, 4, 9), (13, 4, 9), (11, 2, 9), (11, 6, 9), (11, 4, 7), (11, 4, 11), in arbitrary order. (All these have distance 2 from (11, 4, 9).)
the 1521st and final element would be (22, 10, 0) - the point furthest from (11, 4, 9)

The simplest algorithm to do this would be to generate an array of all points in the Cartesian product (1521 of them, in the example), then sort them by distance from the first point, then iterate over the result. But with larger inputs this will be very inefficient, memory-wise. I don't want to store all the points in memory at once; I just need to iterate over them one time.
How can I achieve this in a more memory-efficient way?

First, sort each input array in order of absolute difference from its first element.
After this transformation, if you represent each output as a tuple (i,j,k), then the first output is (0,0,0), and every output after that can be found by taking some preceding output and incrementing i, j, or k by one.
To get your outputs in order:

Put (0,0,0) into a priority queue sorted by distance, and into a set that remembers which tuples you've added to the queue
While the priority queue is not empty:

Take an element out and record the output.
Generate the 3 new tuples by incrementing i, j, and k.
For each one that doesn't exceed the bounds of the input array and isn't present in the set, add it to the set and priority queue.



If you like, you can delete each tuple from the set when you remove it from the queue, since no attempt will be made to add it again.  This reduces the worst case space requirement to O(n2) instead of O(n3)

More generally, I think the worst case space complexity of this algorithm, given m input arrays each of length n, will be O(nᵐ⁻¹), versus O(nᵐ) for the naive algorithm suggested in the question. (It's definitely at least that bad - to see this, consider the case where elements in one of the input arrays are all enormously far from the first element, while other input arrays have all their elements close to the first element.) An improvement, but I wonder if an approach with significantly better overall performance is still possible?

It would have to be very clever.  There can be O(nm-1) points at the same distance.  Add minor perturbations, and there doesn't seem to be any useful restrictions on the possible orderings of those  O(nm-1) points.  They will need to be sorted somehow.  Maybe if you could figure out how to do the 2D case in sublinear space...

Also, while this is a pretty good algorithm (and what I ended up implementing), it doesn't guarantee that we'll get the order we need (but makes it extremely likely). There could be a tuple that is achieved by shifting one index, and so you encounter it before another tuple that requires shifting two of the indices. But the second tuple could still have a smaller distance. This will be more likely to happen if the arrays have wildly varying disparities in the distance between the numbers in them.

That can't happen.  If A->B requires shifting two indices, then there is an x such that A->x->B, where x requires shifting one index and is at an intermediate distance.  The initial sort ensures that.

@MattTimmermans - sorry to bother you again, but thinking more about this, I still think its not exact. Let's say the very first tuple is "0". Its three children are "1", "2" and "3" ("1" has the smallest distance from "0", "2" has second smallest). The tuples that are the three children of "1" are "1.1", "1.2" and "1.3" and so on. It could be possible that "1.1" has a smaller distance than "3" to "0". However, "3" will show up before it per this algorithm. Am I missing something? I don't think the initial sort helps mitigate this?

The priority queue mitigates that.  When "0" is visited, "1", "2", and "3" are enqueued.  Then "1" is visited and its children are enqueued.  Now "1.1" and "3" are both in the queue along with "1.2", "1.3", and "2".  "1.1" will be retrieved from the priority queue before "3", because it has a smaller distance.
